# Azure App Service Unauthorised user access to controller

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I have a script that works fine when the user is authenticated:

```
[MobileAppController]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
// GET api/Test
[HttpGet, Route("api/Test/completeAll")]
public string Get()
{
    MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = this.Configuration.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();
    ITraceWriter traceWriter = this.Configuration.Services.GetTraceWriter();

        string host = settings.HostName ?? "localhost";
        string greeting = "Hello from " + host;

        traceWriter.Info(greeting);
        return greeting;
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost, Route("api/Test/completeAll")]
    public string Post(string hej)
    {
        string retVal = "Hello World!" + hej;
        return retVal;
    }
}
}
```

As can be seen I have not added the attribute `[Authorize]` which is the new way of requiring authentication, [see controller on this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services/). And it is stated in the same link that controllers are now anonymous.

However I get access denied if I try to access the controller before authentication, but after authentication it works fine.

Can anyone clarify this?

**Update**

According to [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-work-with-authentication) I should not change anything because quickstart is installed. And it is but still not working :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization set to require authentication for all requests?

- Go to you App Service in the Azure Portal
- All Settings -> Authentication / Authorization (under FEATURES)
- Under "Action to take when request is not authenticated", set to "Allow request (no action)"

This will let the application control the authorization rather than the service.

Comment: Hello Adrian, Thank you for your answer. I will test it tonight. I just had one question, this change would then let all endpoints be open to unauthorised users. Are there any risk in connection with this? I mean are there any endpoints that I then have to do something manually about to ensure my server? In theory I am only interested in one API being available for unauthorised users, all others I would like the users to be authorised for (and I will therefore add the `[Authorize]` atribute, but it is more if there is another way or it is blunder to do so? :))

Comment: You have two choices - 1) Let the service control auth, 2) you control auth.  You want #2, which means you need to decorate any endpoint you want authenticated with [Authorize].  You get to choose.  If you choose #1, then ALL endpoints are controlled by the service - you don't get to choose.

Comment: Okay thx, the endpoints then are only the ones that I open up? It is not like there comes something in other places that I need to lock in some way ?

Comment: I think of it more as specifying the ones I want to lock down (those decorated with the [Authorize] tag) rather than opening up - although you can use [AllowAnonymous] to tag those.

Comment: so instead of unlocking all I can just add that attribute?

Comment: No - you really need to add an appropriate attribute to everything.  As describe above, you are either in control or you are not in control.  If you choose to be in control, it's up to you to protect the APIs needing protection.